Loading ArcGIS layer to PowerBI
I would like to link my ArcGIS Online layer to PowerBI.
I found this video very useful:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qv3VZzaPKKw&ab_channel=EsriCanada
I was successful with all the steps except locating my data on the map.

In the video, the situation is simple, unlike my layers.
I've prepared one of them in ArcGIS Pro by using:
-> Calculate the Geometry option in the Field Attribute Table
-> XY Table to point
After successfully loading the PowerBI desktop, I can't find my features, which are steadily located in one line.
I've read that the PowerBI mainly accepts the WGS 84 CRS only, but I have the ArcGIS Online linked to it. All my works are in EPSG 27700.
What can be wrong here then?

